# como acceder a un objeto

Tags: javascript, json

buen dia recibo una consulta en Json e intendo mostrar  el name de seller pero  si coloco consulta.seller.name me dice que no existe

Como puedo acceder seller.name para mostrarlo en una variable?

```
[
{
    "id": "2",
    "date": "2021-03-18",
    "dueDate": "2021-03-18",
    "datetime": "2021-03-18 14:10:51",
    "observations": "",
    "anotation": "",
    "termsConditions": "",
    "status": "open",
    "client": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Luis arturo lopez",
        "identification": "",
        "phonePrimary": "",
        "phoneSecondary": "",
        "fax": "",
        "mobile": "",
        "email": "",
        "address": []
    },
    "seller": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Luis ",
        "identification": "Lopez",
        "observations": "es el primer vendedor"
    }
```

]

Comment: Mira que lo que tienes está envuelto en corchetes cuadrados `[ ]` esto quiere decir que tu objeto es  un **array**. Intenta `consulta[0].seller.name` para acceder al primer elemento (en tu caso el único) de tu array.

Answer (score 4):

espero que estes bien, lo primero que debes hacer es acceder a la posicion 0 de el objeto array (que almacena un objeto) luego en el accedes al atributo seller > name.

```js
let info = [
{
    "id": "2",
    "date": "2021-03-18",
    "dueDate": "2021-03-18",
    "datetime": "2021-03-18 14:10:51",
    "observations": "",
    "anotation": "",
    "termsConditions": "",
    "status": "open",
    "client": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Luis arturo lopez",
        "identification": "",
        "phonePrimary": "",
        "phoneSecondary": "",
        "fax": "",
        "mobile": "",
        "email": "",
        "address": []
    },
    "seller": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Luis ",
        "identification": "Lopez",
        "observations": "es el primer vendedor"
    }
    }
    ]
    
 console.log(info[0].seller.name);
```